# jquery ui tabs : selecting tab but how do I load the content from text file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

Beginner. I have a tab control that has content loaded dynamically via links. These are simple text files. So you click tab 3, it grabs the content from the text file and loads it. real basic.

On tab 2 i have a button that I want to get to tab 3 with passing an ID value. I can do this in the worst way possible to make it work but I have another issue. If i use:

```
$('#myTabs').tabs({selected:2});
```

it opens tab3 but it will not load the content. Everything else works fine, I just don't know what I am missing, or doing wrong in order to get the content to load.

Appreciate any help as always!

This is what I have for loading the tabs

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myTabs').tabs({selected: '0'});  
});
```

```
<div id='myTabs'>
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="/scripts/content2.txt">Content Area 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/scripts/content3.txt">Content Area 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

won't bother with the content for tab 1...all this works. I can click any tab and get what I am suppose to get. so lets say that content3.txt contains this (also each text contain links to libraries and style sheets):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#testing').text('Hello World');
});
```

and content2.txt contains a button click event that switches to content3.txt:

```
$('#thisBtn').click(function () {
$('#myTabs').tabs({selected:2});
$('#myTabs').load('/scripts/content3.txt', function () {
   alert('worked');
});
```

the above wipes out the tabs...i guess because I am using the div that the tabs are contained within and loading different content to it? So my issue is that the div 'texting' is within the text file and doesn't get loaded until the tab is selected? does that make sense.

finally how to I change this/ improve this? etc.

Comment: You should not be loading the content into `myTabs`. Check the update to my answer. It explains where the content should be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not loading any content from what you have given us, you are only switching tabs. You would have to use something like jquery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). The below code will load the contents of `myTextFile.txt` into the element with the id of `result`.

```
$('#result').load('myTextFile.txt', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

The general layout of jquery ui tabs is the following html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div> <--- Load content into these divs
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see each tab has an id assigned to it. You need to load the content into the correct div that corresponds with the tab you are wanting to load.

Comment: Thanks Josh. The above is actually what I was asking for. I tried load and it worked, but it wipes out the tabs....loads the content though.

Comment: You are most likely choosing the wrong element to load the content into. I believe each tab should have its own content div correct? You should be loading the content into the corresponding tabs div.

Comment: yeah....i believe that is it sir. makes sense...thanks for helping a beginner! appreciated!

Comment: so this actually helped point out another problem I have now by understanding a little more about the above. the 'target' div doesnt exist until the text file gets loaded. these text files contain all the source for the content per tab. have to start looking at this one, but i appreciate the above all the more. thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by the target is within the text file too? The tabs actually div should be on the page itself not loaded in as well.

Comment: so perhaps I am misunderstanding then. the tabs div itself is on the page. 'myTabs', but if I use $('#myTabs').load(link) then it loads the content from the text file, but wipes out the tabs control all together. If I am understanding the above, you are saying aim it at a div that should exist within the tabs content right? don't load it to the div that the tab uses, but a div within the tab 3 content? So I will add everything I have got above like I should have done to begin with :)

Comment: I am going to update my answer instead of trying to explain it in comments.

Comment: The main content divs that the tabs are being loaded into should be on the main page. I am not sure there is really a good way around that. All you need to do is have the placeholder div there. You can still load all the content into it.